# tippecanoe: assign random uuids to clusters, preserve ids for non-clusters

Tags: geojson, tippecanoe

I have a large geographic dataset, including lots of points, that I'm creating an Mapbox vector tileset from using [`tippecanoe`](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe). Rather than dropping points, I'm clustering points. Separately, the original GeoJSON features have a unique id that I want to preserve in the tiles.

The trouble is showing up when I try to combine the two. I'm currently building tiles like this:

`tippecanoe -o tiles/points.mbtiles -r1 -Z8 -z11 --cluster-distance=10 --use-attribute-for-id=unique_id geojson/points.geojson`

The result is that all un-clustered features have the correct feature `id` (preserved from the original `unique_id` field). All well and good. But the resulting **clustered** features also have an `id` that comes from one of the features that make up the cluster.

Is it possible to tell `tippecanoe` to assign ids to clusters differently? Ideally, they'd be `uuid`s.

I did try changing the options like this:

`tippecanoe -o tiles/points.mbtiles -r1 -Z8 -z11 --cluster-distance=10 -y unique_id geojson/points.geojson`

This just preserves `unique_id` in the features' `properties` objects, and still gives features `id`s in the same way as above.